# I have a null-pointer exception in fuction and don't know how to fix it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The function is:

```
public Integer[] details;
private void putDetails(Integer l){
    if (l != null){
        int n = new Integer(0);
        n = details[l];
        details[l]=n+1;
    }
}
```

The error message say:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at operacional.an_lex.putDetails(an_lex.java:30)
```

where the line 30 is : `n = details[l];`

Can you help me?

Comment: Clearly you haven't initialized the `detalles` array.

Comment: Where is that hammer... Oh there he is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Sorry, detalles is in spanish. I translate that to english but I forget translate that word.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `details` array:

```
//some number is the size of the array
int[] details = new int[some number];
```

or you can initialize like so if you want to fill the elements with 0's:

```
int[] details = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
```

What is happening is that you are getting an element from the `details` array, but that element doesn't have value. I'd check to make sure you have an assigned value in that array's element.

Comment: I tried that but is the same error ...

Comment: @TekolinSum I'd suggest you post the rest of your code then. Otherwise, we can't help much more.

Comment: @TekolinSum Even when you initialize `details` with `Integer[] details = new Integer[10];` this array will be filled with `nulls`, and since `n` is `int` it can't store `null` returned by `details[l];`. You will need to fill your array with proper Integers first.

Comment: You opened my mind. That´s the error. I write now : `public Integer details[] = new Integer[4];` but how can I fill the 4 positions with zero without writing 4 lines using `details[0]=0; details[1]=0;` ?

Comment: @TekolinSum Simplest way would be... not using `Integer` but `int` array which is by default filled with zeroes.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai `int` array is by default filled with `0` so `{0,0,0,0}` part in case of `new int[]` is redundant. This array initialization part can be useful if type of array is `Integer` or if you want to set array content to something different then default values.

Comment: Thank you Masters !!!  Now everything is ok !